# Am I allowed to process personal data on a cloud server?

Tags: data, legal-issues

I have gathered some fMRI and eye tracking data, from several subjects. I can process them using the server in our lab, but I would like to take advantage of my own cloud servers on Linode and DigitalOcean, even EC2.

Before these data were gathered, in the consent form we did not mention the possibilities that data might be processed/stored in the cloud.

Am I allowed to use cloud servers to process these data under current regulations? Does it makes any difference if these servers were purchased/rented under my lab's name?

Comment: I don't know what "regulations" would exist to govern this. It sounds more  like something your IRB would have to approve.

Comment: +1 to @NateEldredge's comment. It would be *very* good if your data were first anonymized suitably.

Comment: Good question, anyway, +1. I took the liberty of editing it a bit to emphasize that we are talking about *personal* data in the title. Feel free to roll back or improve my edits.

Comment: @NateEldredge, HIPAA in the US coould be construed to cover this very easily. Unless the cloud provider has a BAA in place with Quan's university to guarantee the correct data protection, there could be trouble.

Comment: @BillBarth but eye tracking and to an extent fMRI data are not PHI so HIPAA compliance should not be an issue.

Comment: @StrongBad, since when is an fMRI not PHI?

Comment: Data protection law varies by country. What country are you in? Are the cloud servers in the same country? (or if you're in the EU, are the servers also within the EU?)

Comment: I wrote a paper covering this. I don't recall what section. When I look over it again I'll point it out. http://albertkung.com/files/RP_IA_18Aug2013.pdf for the U.S. specifically

Comment: @AE: This is a very crucial point. Where you are in the world makes a huge difference. For instance, it's technically not allowed for German researchers to share their results via Dropbox, because the servers are not based in Germany. No way would you be able to put personal data on a cloud server not based in Germany—and even then you'd have a hard time getting around privacy laws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To some extent, the answer depends on location. In the US, IRBs tend to be concerned with [Protected Health Information (PHI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information). There are 18 things that are considered PHI and generally these can be easily stripped from research data. For fMRI and eye tracking data, you need to be a little concerned about two components of PHI

> Biometric identifiers, including finger, retinal and voice prints
>
> Full face photographic images and any comparable images

In the UK the term is [Personal Data](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/key-definitions/) and the definition is:

> Personal data means data which relate to a living individual who can be identified –
>
> (a) from those data, or
>
> (b) from those data and other information which is in the possession of, or is likely to come into the possession of, the data controller

Most people provide a data storage and archiving plan that outlines how they protect PHI/Personal Data in their IRB ethics application. Most IRBs that I am familiar with do not consider fMRI to be comparable to a full face photograph or allow the individual to be identified. This is despite fMRI researchers often being able to recognize each other's brains. Most eye tracking data that I am familiar with do not include high resolution images of the retina and would not be classified at PHI/Personal Data. People publish pictures of fMRI slices and eye tracking traces all the time. Prior to uploading data onto the cloud, you will want to confirm with your IRB what they consider PHI/Personal Data.

Answer (score 2):

The applicable regulations don't directly apply to you as an individual, they apply to your institution. The institution in turn states what is and is not allowed. My former institution had a policy (stemming from FERPA) which required any email to or about a student to be encrypted, and could only be sent from a university-owned computer on-campus. This is well above the requirements actually imposed by FERPA -- it's erring on the side of caution.

You may be able to determine that there is a policy prohibiting or allowing such data storage, and I would bet that it is prohibited. The university has to be certain that personal data is secure, so except for a monumental oversight on the university's part, they surely would be some policy. You need to trace through the policy documents and see if, for example, they say that restricted data can only be put out there via a university-sponsored Box account.

Comment: I have never heard of fMRI or eye tracking data as being consider personal since it is, by it nature, anonymous. The data don't even need to be anonymised, since there is nothing personal in them.

Comment: Nameless voice data is "personal" since it can theoretically identify an individual, even if there is no name associated with it. The data do need to be anonymized, unless you have obtained consent from subjects to be identified. It doesn't matter if it's not anything you would personally care about, it's about informed consent. If the server data is anonymized you (she) are probably okay, save for a quirky interpretation of policy by the institution.

Comment: @StrongBad, fMRI data is *not* anonymous unless it has been anonymized. If a scan of your brain with your name on it exists, that's PHI.

Comment: @BillBarth your name is PHI, the fMRI data are not. If the name is included in the fMRI data set, the data set needs to be anonymised. Many research scanners either do not use names and/or produce "clean" data sets. I have never seen eye tracking data with a name or ID number embedded.

Comment: @StrongBad, none of what you say is in evidence here. We don't know the provenance of the data except that OP did the scanning. It could be from a clinical scanner at a university associated hospital, etc. Given the level of statutory fines, I would consult with my university's HIPAA compliance officer rather that just assume you can anonymize it or that it is already sufficiently anonymized. Further consultation with the IRB is probably also required.

Comment: "The applicable regulations don't directly apply to you as an individual, they apply to your institution. The institution in turn states what is and is not allowed." - [citation (for the general validity of this statement) needed]

Comment: 42 USC 289: “The Secretary shall by regulation require that each entity which applies for a grant… to review biomedical and behavioral research involving human subjects conducted at or supported by such entity…”. It's more involved, but that is the core statute. 45 CFR 46.101(a) recognises the scope limitation to research supported the federal government -- see subsequently 103 "Each institution ... shall provide written assurance...".

Comment: @user6726, how do you know OP is in the USA? Here in the EU this would be a matter of law, some of which does apply to individuals as well as to institutions.

Comment: I don't know: this is why people need to give appropriate context when asking questions. Otherwise, people will supply whatever seems appropriate to a question about "current regulations".